# Function return reference in C++

Tags: c++, return-value

```
double& squaredX (double x)
{
   return x*x;
}
```

1. What would be the potential problem of this function?
2. What is the best way to rewrite the function?

Comment: You don't say what language you're using, which makes helping you hard. In any case, the `&` looks like a typo to me.

Comment: Assuming that this is C++, you're returning a reference to a temporary.

Comment: I think this possibly belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This doesn't even compile, you cannot bind a temporary to a non-const reference.

Answer (score 1):

1. What would be the potential problem of this function?

It doesn't compile, because you cannot bind a non-const reference to a temporary (which is the result of `x*x`, a temporary `int`, and the return type of `double&` is not even compatible) and even if you correct for that, you are returning a reference of a local variable which is incorrect, as the variable goes out of scope when the function returns.

2. What is the best way to rewrite the function?

The type of `x*x` is `int`, so it makes sense to return an `int`

```
int squaredX (int x)
{
   return x*x;
}
```

It's possible that the result of `x*x` is too large to fit into an `int`, in which case you may want to use a larger type for the calculation and return value. But that depends on the particulars of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

One way that could be "better" is to use templates and universal forwarding references (C++11 or newer).

```
 template<typename T>
 T square(const T&& x)
 {
     return x*x;
 }
```

T could be `double` , `int8_t`,`int` , `MyComplexMath::Quaternion` ... anything that supports `operator*`. It also supports pass by reference in case the argument is expensive to copy.

Arguably, this might (rightly so) scare away people, so may not "best". It still doesn't address overflows.

Comment: If you are going in that direction, you might as well provide the output as a reference parameter to avoid copying the return value, and use `*=` which tends to be more efficient when used with classes.

Comment: @NeilKirk - you mean return a reference instead of a value? That's usually not recommended - compiler RVO (Return Value Optimization) should avoid the copy of the return value. `*=` is non-const -- that seems like a deal breaker.

Comment: No I mean that a reference is passed as a parameter. RVO won't change the fact that `x*x` allocates a temporary object. If it is a class, it may allocate dynamic memory.

Comment: @NeilKirk - you are right, I'm confusing RVO with inline optimizations. Most compilers would inline it and hopefully avoid a copy.